# Need To build a REGEX to be placed in javascript

Tags: regex

MY Regex :

```
/^[\s]*(\'[a-zA-Z0-9_:\.\-\s\\\/\(\)\&\>\<]+(\,+\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_:\.\-\s\\\/\(\)\&\>\<]+)*\'[\s\,]*)*$/
```

I want it to Validate ::

```
'A','B,C','D','E,F','G','H'....... // like wise no specific pattern
```

Here, 'A' can be a word or sentence and same goes for other Letters mentioned above.

Invalid cases ::

```
A','B'    // Missing single quote
'A''B'    // Missing comma
A',B'     // Missing single quote
'A','B    // Missing single quote 
'A','B',  // Extra comma
'A',,'B'  // Double comma
,'A','B'  // Comma at beginning
```

Some of these invalid cases are not being catched by my REGEX.
What should I change in my regex?

I have tested it on https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex to invalidate all strings you've shown in your question:

```sh
/^\s*'[^']*'(?:,'[^']*')*\s*$/gm
```

Assumption is that there is no escaping of single quotes in your input.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/D9M6O4/1)

**RegEx Details;**

- `^`: Start
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `'[^']*'`: Match a single quoted string
- `(?:,'[^']*')*`: Match comma followed by a single quoted string. Math 0 or more of this group
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `$`: End

If escaped single quotes i.e. `\'` can be part of input then you may use:

```sh
/^\s*'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*'(?:,'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*')*\s*$/gm
```